# How would I use PHP to authenticate with Linux users and passwords?

Tags: php, linux, authentication

Say I wanted to create something like how cPanel works, it uses the username and password from the system.

You can run 'passwd user' on the server, and the password would still work with cPanel and FTP (not necessarily MySQL, but you get the point)

How would I accomplish this in PHP? I haven't the slightest idea, besides running /bin/su locally and running from that. With that, it might be inaccurate though.. I usually have a few of my developers either on a sub-account, or on root developing something.

Any ideas would greatly be appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Do you want to (1) authenticate with system username/passwords or (2) actually run code from a webserver as the specific user?

Comment: I'd like to authenticate with the username and password. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

PAM:  http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM

In Debian /'buntu packages, it is probably as easy as installing php5-auth-pam, and using the function:

```
pam_auth($username,$password,$error);
```

Although it seems to rely on ancient php4 syntax, 'cause I get an error if I don't use the deprecated way of passing by reference at call time:

```
if(!pam_auth($username,$password,&$error)){
    echo 'No access, PAM said: '.$error;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen this module before. I'll experiment with it and see how it goes.

Comment: A bit dated, but, can this access accounts that are in the shadow file ? I want to sync with accounts already on the server to simply authentication with a web app.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm locally that it works out-of-the-box here with debian + php5-auth-pam + shadow file, so probably on most linux based osses.

Comment: While I was trying to use this, I discovered that for LAMP systems, apache is running a non-root user (of course!), making it not possible to use this method, without allowing the apache user to access pam_passwd, or better, pam_tally* in the root-only security section of the linux OS. But a server administrator will not do this, because this opens up a gap and an invitation for any hackers. Am I correct with this?

Comment: @FlorianMertens: the requisite is the user is either root or the user authenticating, or able to read the /etc/shadow file. In Debian, it would be as simple as adding the `shadow` group to the apache user. Whether _"a"_ sysadmin would do this: I would on otherwise protected boxes (no direct ssh access is possible, ssh access requires valid keys, proper firewall, non-shared, sane user permissions, otherwise trusted code in the webserver, etc.). For a bit more security one might run a deamon instead which answers on questions of the apache user. But the need would have to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to authenticate. In any case, you could use PAM with PHP:
http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM

There is that PHP function:
posix_getpwnam

You could use that quite straight forward as well.