# How do I use the Linux PAM module in a custom script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pam

I'm working on a program that would value from using the built in PAM module of linux, for authentication and verifying user entered credentials. I've been trying to research how it's implemented, however much documentation I find is old and usually deleted, and I have trouble finding many examples of it being used in a casual script.

Can someone help me understand how PAM would be used with a custom script, specifically to pass a username and password for authentication, and maybe point me to documentation on how to use it?

Comment: Something missing in `sudo`? What do you mean by "use" PAM in a script? What do you want to "use" and how exactly?

Comment: @KamilCuk I would like to have script that can intake a uername and password in a set of strings, and verify if it matches to a user on the local system

The strings are gathered from an html page i made, and passed as variables. I would like to use these and verify them through Linux's PAM system. Hope this helps clarify

Comment: Have you tried `apropos pam` in the bash and tried to read through the manual pages to get a start of coding?

Comment: So you are implementing php pam_auth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765304/how-would-i-use-php-to-authenticate-with-linux-users-and-passwords ? So, maybe again, any reason not to use `sudo -S`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am using php to pass the variables, but I didn't know about this package! It looks perfect too! i'll get on it and let you know how it goes!!

Comment: @KamilCuk, so the link you brought up is from 2010, and php-pam was deprecated from atleast debian systems around 2015. I tried installing it from pecl, however the code doesnt seem to be working. I can't find a lot of support of it being a solution used today.

Moving onto the `sudo -S` code, I had to find a laymans version of how it's explained in the man pages, but this is looking like the solution! Running a simple `printf ""$password"\n" | sudo -u $username -S echo "1"` for example does work for verification!!

If you want to make an answer out of this, i'll mark it as "solved"!!

Comment: Makes sense, I believe the usual solution is LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sudo` to check the password.

```
printf "%s" "$password" | sudo -n -S -u "$username" true
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help! I'll also look more into ldap to see how it functions with pam!